# Phpmyadmin Insert data between two already inserted?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database setup and was inserting data into it. However I noticed that I missed a bit to insert. So how do I insert that data between two existing pieces in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a relational database like MySQL, there isn't really a particular order inherent to the table. You should sort by particular columns when retrieving information if order is important to you (such as alphabetical by last name, or numerically by order number). Other than that, MySQL does generally happen to show information in the order it was inserted, but relying on this can cause problems (such as re-ordering when missing a line during insert, or if an item is removed).

So the proper solution is really to sort by some reliable means (perhaps a "sort_order" INT column or time stamp for last modification time), but the only workaround to that would be to manually (or programmatically) move each value up by one. You can do this directly with SQL, although you have to be careful to not to change too many values. Make sure you have a backup first.

Once you have a backup of your table, you need another copy of the table. In this example, I've got 'sorter' and 'sorter2' which are identical, and have two columns; 'id' and 'val'.

```sql
UPDATE sorter, sorter2
SET sorter.val = sorter2.val
WHERE sorter.id = sorter2.id +1 AND sorter.id > 15
```

This can be expanded to include more columns and of course the AND statement should be adapted to fit whichever row you're inserting the new data. The easiest way to use this would be to add another row at the end (which can be blank or have garbage data, since the second-to-last row will soon replace it), then run the SQL which will move everything up one, leaving you a duplicated space at whatever row matches your AND statement for you to manually insert the missing information.

But again, I recommend using a better sorting means if order is important to you.